# User's generated specifications

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, specifications

I want to let my users create specifications to be executed in a nhibernate.Linq query.

Is it possible? I ask the user to write a query string (HQL I suppose) so it will be serializable and in a combobox the user can apply it to current results

Comment: So the user specifies a query and your app executes it?  Are there any security restrictions you may want to implement besides limiting access to certain users?

Answer (score 1):

Linq expressions are not serializable.

HQL, on the other hand, is just a string like SQL, so that would work.

But you have to really trust your user, as there is nothing stopping him from typing "DELETE TheMostImportantEntity WHERE 1=1".

Comment: Yes, it's true.
Another problem is that user doesn't know the exact class properties name so it's not so easy to create query expression.

I'll go with a combobox of precompiled Specifications to choose between, for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

One other option may be using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library (see details here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx )